# Use JSON path in ini file

Tags: python, json, ini, configparser

I want to read the json values from config json file. The json object path I use in my python code is like below:

```
jsonfile['Data'][0]['Tenants'][0]['TenPropertyGroup']
```

Now I want to pass this above path `"['Data'][0]['Tenants'][0]['TenPropertyGroup']"` from ini file to make sure I can make changes in ini file if the object path gets changed in json file.

My `config.ini` looks like:

```
[CONFIG]
TenPropertyGroup= ['Data'][0]['Tenants'][0]['TenPropertyGroups']
```

My python code after reading from ini file looks like

```
globalconfig = "config.ini"
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(globalconfig)

f = open(configfile, )
jsonfile = json.load(f)

TenPropertyGroup = config['CONFIG']['TenPropertyGroup']

TenPropertyGroups = (str(jsonfile ) + TenPropertyGroup)
```

But when I am reading in Python using `configparser` the above PropertyGroup is of string data type and I am not able to get the list from json file.

I am trying to read this ini properly from python code but not able to convert it to object.

Comment: `eval(TenPropertyGroups)`?

Comment: ```eval(TenPropertyGroups)``` is giving error as ```invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach. You should avoid executing text read from a file for security reasons. If you use a different format for you *ini* file value, you could parse it and use the values to drill down into you json object. Here's a simple example:

```
path_from_ini = 'x/y/z'

json_dict = { 'x' : { 'y' : { 'z' : 42 } } }

parts = path_from_ini.split('/')
v = json_dict

# Drill down into the JSON dictonary
for p in parts:
    v = v[p]

print(v)
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response, but I wanted to make the path independent of code, because if my json object gets changed in given json file then I will need to change the code again to make changes in path. e.g. if path from ```x/y/z``` gets changed to ```x/w/y/z``` then I will need to change ```config.ini``` and my Python file also.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it did solve my problem. Initially I misunderstood the ```json_dict``` part from your code. Later I got it and tried the solution and it is working. Thanks a lot for help